# IOS Push notification for messaging app

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, messaging, whatsapp

I am working with a messaging app and the app needs to receive the notification from the server (chat message). I am facing the problem when receiving the silent notification, most of the notification can’t received by the device, the scenario as below:

1. iOS 10 – Bring the app into background and push the silent notification, all notification can receive by the device.
2. iOS 11 – Bring the app into background and push the silent notification, device only can receive first 10 notifications and the rest of the notification disappear, I try to reboot the device and put the app into the background, able to receive another few notification and after that all not receive again.
3. Both iOS 10 and 11 – Kill the app and push the silent notification, all the notifications not receive.

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       logging(cls: self, mod: "APP", msg: "Did receive remote notification")
   }
   ```

I try the Whatsapp push notification, even I kill the app and turn off the background app refresh in setting, all the notification still come in, I’m curious how Whatsapp handle the push notification?

How do I solve this notification issue?

Comment: Hey did you able to solve this? Any heads-up?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use XMPP server base for live chat.

XMPP server has RTC ( Real time communication ) protocol, where 2 or more parties can connect, exchange document, live chat, video call, audio call etc.

You can also integrate websocket, for knowing user is online / office and other activities.

Integrating apple push, is not a 100% solution for live chat app like whatsapp, facebook messager, skype etc.

[Get more information about Pushkit](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 8, Apple introduced a new kind of push notification service called VoIP push. VoIP push is provided by the Apple's [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) framework.

Normal push notification service has the following **drawbacks**,

- Delivery: Apple doesn't promise a delivery time or priority.
- Need permission to send push: Not all users understand that they need to allow it to receive calls.
- The app doesn't know about a push until the user decides to act on the push.
- Apple might throttle your push messages if you send too many.

Now coming to PushKit framework,

The benefits of **PushKit framework** are,

- You don't need to allow push; it works without the user knowing about it.
- Apple promises to deliver these push notifications high priority.
- Your push notifications won't get lost.
- You have total control over push notifications.

So, for messaging apps like yours, the usage of PushKit framework is recommended. Here is a [tutorial](https://github.com/rizwan95/ios-pushkit-tutorial) on Github which explains how to implement PushKit in your apps.

Comment: Can we use the voip pushkit without voice support in the app?

Comment: Many apps are using VoIP push without VoIP calling. So give it a try :)

Comment: Update- Looks like Apple is not approving apps with PushKit support without VoIP calls.